# Meteor/mongo get records created one month ago

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, momentjs

How do I get records from my collection created one month ago with **moment.js** return a count of all the records.

My collection code is:

```
Products.find() // where start and end date is one month ago and  products is the collection
```

This might be a silly question but, as I am coming from rails to javascript/meteor, a little help will be fine.

sample document

```
 {
        "_id": "xxx",
        "name": "xxx",
        "description": "xxx",
        "createdAt": "2015-04-18T04:40:00Z",
        "productType": "Flavoured Milk",
        "opt1": "Packaging",
        "opt2": "Weight",
        "supplier": "xxx",
        "brand": "xxx"
        "status": "active",
        "tags": ["xxx","xxx"],
        "updatedAt": "2015-04-18T04:40:00Z"
    }
```

Comment: Uchenna, what have you tried? also are you measuring from the day they were created? or the `start` and `end date`? Can you write out a sample of one of your `documents`?

Comment: This question needs at the very least a document example to be answerable.

Comment: @inspired and i have updated my question

Comment: i am measuring from one month before now

Comment: I tried it out all the answers before posting this question and it did not work. Having a little look at my documents again and just noticed i dont have any created one month ago. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Date object of one month ago by:

```
moment().subtract(1, "months").toDate();
```

I assume that you have field `createdAt` on `Products` collection. So the query to find all products created on month ago will be:

```
var oneMonthAgo = moment().subtract('months', 1).toDate();

Products.find({ createdAt: oneMonthAgo })
```

But keep in mind that the solution above will return only records that created at **exactly** one month ago **accurate to second**.

Comment: I actually had trying this out in mind but was not sure it will work. But will try it out. thanks

Comment: Your answer is deprecated. it should be number before period.

Comment: @UchennaOkafor thanks. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Uchenna,

In `Moment.js 2.8.0` you could do something as such:

`var comparison = moment().subtract(1, 'months').toDate();`

`Products.find({ createdAt: comparison });`

According to the docs:

> Before version 2.8.0, the moment#subtract(String, Number) syntax was
>   also supported. It has been deprecated in favor of
>   moment#subtract(Number, String).

Comment: yea figured it out. Its just me being lazy. Thanks